# Track of structure changes in a Progress database

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I am asked to automate the tracking of changes in the structure of the database: Any modification, addition or removal of tables, fields, indexes, etc.

I have searched the audit but only found that it can track changes in the "*Database schema*", which is something else.

Do you know if it is possible to do that?

We use 11.6.3.

Comment: The items that you listed: "modification, addition or removal of tables, fields, indexes" are all "database schema".  How is that "something else" or different from what you said that you need to track?

Comment: Thank you, Tom.
I guess I misunderstood, but I believed that "Database schema" is the .st file content.

Comment: The .st file is the "structure" file. That is not related to the schema. The structure can be changed independently of the schema. Schema is the tables, fields, and indexes of the database. Also sometimes known as the dictionary or catalog.

Comment: I found some days ago other document that refers to the structure as "Schema". That confused me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

One wonders how those magical changes in the schema (I think you clarified that it was actually schema changes you wanted to automate) occur. Optionally it could be up to those making the changes to also keep track of them. Usually (hopefully) the database is updated using "delta df-files". Those df-files if kept are a changelog of the database.

Another option is to daily/hourly/weekly dump the data definitions:

```
CREATE ALIAS DICTDB FOR DATABASE sports.
DISPLAY LDBNAME("DICTDB").

RUN prodict/dump_df.p   ("ALL",
                         "c:/temp/sports.df",
                          "").

DELETE ALIAS DICTDB. /* Optional */
```

Taken from this entry in the knowledge base: https://community.progress.com/s/article/15884

Then you can diff that df-file using your favorite tool or keep as it is.

If you actually mean structure (that's more how the data is stored in different files on disc) you can use the prostrct command to save a new st-file to disc:

```
prostrct list sports
```

This will save a file called sports.st. Handle it as above and you will have a changelog of the database structure.

Comment: Thank you, Jensd.   Yes, we use .df for update the DB structure and we keep track of the changes.    But we have a kind of new bosses and they want it automated.

Comment: I now have three ways to do it: Use the audit tables, your prodict solution and use the VST tables. I like them all.

Comment: Pick the one that suit your specific needs!

Comment: The audit tables will be.